# Ubuntu 20.04 USB Suddenly not working

Tags: usb

I have here a Toshiba Satellite Pro A50-EC-124 I5-8GB-256GB with the Ubuntu 20.04.2LTS.

Suddenly the two Usb's on the right side stopped working. Those two are USB 3.0

When I connect my phone to the laptop using the USB 3.0 port I see that my phone receives electricity. But my phone won't show the normal window asking to connect to the laptop. Also tested with an external USB mouse and keyboard but no success.

Strange thing is when I connect my 2TB external hard disk to one of those 3.0 ports. It works just fine. Only my phone it dont reads, When I stick my phone in the 2.0 on the same laptop it will connect to it.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Seems phone does not support USB 3. Also I do not see how this has anything to do with Ubuntu. It is a hardware problem.

Comment: Did you actually read my post? If not than look out for the key-word ¨suddenly¨

Before those two USB 3.0 did work with my phone and mouse and keyboard.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a hardware problem, but rather some driver/device recognition issue. USB-3.0 is downwards compatible to USB-2 and USB-1 on the software side (but not necessarily the connector side).

Comment: Any ideas how to fix this issue?